# woocommerce не работает "на странице категории" " показывать подкатегории"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

почему на сайте вордпресс с вукомерс не работает данная настройка. на странице категории продолжают показываться товары?

Comment: Сформулируйте нормально свой вопрос

Comment: мне нужно чтобы на странице категорий товаров показывались подкатегории. а уже на странице конечной подкатегории сами товары. у ву есть во внешний вид -настроить такая настройка, но даже ее выставив ее всеравно продолжает показывать товары.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять тему. Какая сейчас используется?